# How do I get sqldatareader to show the data in the fields?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have an sql server table located on my website (remote). The table is called `table1` and contains a bunch of fields. My goal here is to read all the fields of `table1` into an array to iterate.

Here is my attempt:

```
 private static void ShowFields()
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='table1'", connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            //connection.Close();

            int colCount = reader.FieldCount;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this nearly works, but it shows all the properties of the table, rather than the the data in the fields---e.g., varchar, 50 dao, table etc.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jtbco.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want the actual data IN the table, however you're querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA which gives you data ABOUT the tables/columns/whatever...

So just query the table like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
```

I don't know the column names in your table but if you want just some of the columns to show you can replace the * with a column list:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1
```

where col1, col2 and col3 are just the names of the columns.

Is this what you were going for, or am I way off the mark here?